# Doesn't show the correct numberpage of the bibliography using Bibtex

Tags: table-of-contents, bibtex, bibliographies, page-numbering

Using bibtex, I can't get the right numberpage of the bibliography in the table of contents. The toc shows the last number page of the bibliography, so that in my case, at the bottom of the table of contents  I've got "9 Bibliography  75" but it should be "71". I can't fix it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\pdfpagewidth
\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight
\paperheight
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\geometry{a4paper,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=4cm, lmargin=3.7cm,rmargin=3.7cm} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{splitbib}
  \begin{document}
\cite{example}

\begingroup
\pagestyle{plain}
\sloppy
\begin{category}[]{name}
  \SBentries{example}
\end{category}


\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{name of the bib file}
\addtocounter{chapter}{1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\bibname}

\endgroup


\end{document}
```

Comment: Well your `\addcontentsline` command is *after* the bibliography so naturally it stores the page number from the end of the bibliography.

Comment: As @UlrikeFischer mentioned:  Just flip those lines: first `\addcontentsline` than `\bibliography`.

Comment: Sorry, I've also tried this way, but what I obtain is even worse. Putting the \addcontentstline command before results in the toc showing the page number of the previous chapter.

Comment: take a look at this question: [Wrong page number in contents](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/199599).  the best answers are in the comments.

Comment: It can't be worse, it can be at most two pages off and not 4 like now. Add a \newpage before the \addcontentsline.

Comment: Or see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48511/36296

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've just tried putting \newpage, now the toc shows the pagenumber of the page before. It stands 74, but should be 75. Getting closer!

Comment: Using \cleardoublepage instead \newpage worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As in the comments: this is the code-snippet, that will do:

```
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}\bibname}
\bibliography{name of the bib file}
```

:-)

Comment: Or look at the `tocbibind` package.